# Get access to USB stick in Electron app fails with: No device selected exception

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, webusb

Hello I'm trying to get access to a usb stick from an electron application written in reactjs.

Since electron is a google chromium I thought I can use the USB Web-Api: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/USB

So I created a component like this:

```
import React from 'react';

const UsbAccessButton = () => (
  <button
    className="usb-access-button"
    onClick={() => {
      navigator.usb
        .requestDevice({ filters: [{ vendorId: 0x0951 }] })
        .then(device => {
          console.log(device.productName);
          console.log(device.manufacturerName);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }}
  >
    Get USB Access
  </button>
);

export default UsbAccessButton;
```

The vendorId is the correct one for my specific USB stick. But when I click on the button I get a error like this:

```
DOMException: No device selected.       usb-access-button.component.jsx:14
```

But I want to list the devices available so the user can choose between. So maybe I didn't understand some parts of the docs or what is causing problems here?

UPDATE:
When I run this app inside my default chrome browser I get the dialogue to choose between the usb devices. So it looks like this error is more related to electron itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not currently (January 2020) possible to have a device chooser for WebUSB in Electron - see the issue here: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/14545

At the moment the suggested solution is to use the [thegecko/webusb](https://github.com/thegecko/webusb) polyfill, that uses the node-usb library instead.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I also tried this webusb but I coudn't bring it to work in my react application. I think there is a configuration issue there but also the documentation is very weak in my opinion. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59772849/how-to-configure-external-module-webusb-in-package-json-in-electron-react-js-p

Comment: I have been using [node-usb](https://github.com/tessel/node-usb) in an Electron & React app without any problems (without any WebUSB polyfills), but I hope to switch to WebUSB once the above issue is resolved, as node-usb is using a pretty old fork of libusb.

Comment: how have you implemented it? Can you please show me your configuration in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59772849/how-to-configure-external-module-webusb-in-package-json-in-electron-react-js-p

Comment: That thread has been deleted. To clarify, I'm using node-usb instead of WebUSB in Electron, until the issue to create a device chooser for WebUSB in Electron is resolved.

Comment: Has it been resolved yet? I wanted to use Electron for a WebUSB based project.

Comment: No, but node-usb v2 (https://github.com/node-usb/node-usb#apis) now allows you to use WebUSB code in Electron.

Answer (score 1):

WebUSB support was added in Electron v23.0.0 according to the change log here

- https://www.electronjs.org/blog/electron-23-0#new-features

However, it appears to have had some issues with Mac Arm machines which was fixed in v24 branch.

And finally the WebUSB was opened to all devices (developer opt-in, since it is a security issue) in a later version of v24.